# Copy Vim Version Information to Clipboard

Tags: vim

I am using gvim 7.3 on Windows 7 64 bit Professional. Within vim I can type :version to get information about my vim installation. How can I copy this version information to the clipboard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
:redir @+> | version | redir END
```

Unlike @Gareth McCaughan solution this will send `:version` output directly to clipboard register.

Comment: Oh, nice. I didn't know about `redir @+>`.

Comment: Big 'woah' moment there. That is one underrated obscure vim feature.

Comment: @sehe This feature should be omitted in scripts whenever possible: there are no nested redirections, so any new redirection will override existing one.

Comment: Yeah, but it beats the crap out of e.g. `let @a="" | g/buf/silent! -1,+2 yank A` to get stuff into registers

Answer (score 1):

```
:redir > C:\path\to\my\file.txt
:version
:redir END
```

and then open the file and copy the data from there. If you need to do it automagically in a Vim script, you can make Vim read the file into a buffer and copy the contents into the `+` register. That's more work, though, and I suspect you want this for a one-off purpose for which doing it manually will suffice.